# How to display specific data from JSON using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Our company wants to display job offers that we advertise into a large job offering website. They give us a JSON to display the jobs of our company on our own website.

I want to show some key data in an overview and if you click a link, you'll redirect to a page where detailed data is shown.

The JSON is like:

```
[
{
"Position": "Developer",
"Date": "now",
"Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
{
"Position": "Secretary",
"Date": "next month",
"Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
{
"Title": "Postman",
"Date": "now",
"Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
]
```

My HTML file for the overview page is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json, status) {
    if (status === "error") {
        $("#textNoData").html("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        return;
    }
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<h5>" + json[i].Title + "</h5>");
        tr.append("<strong>Date:</strong> " + json[i].Date + "<p>&nbsp;</p>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
</script>
 <div id="div-for-json"></div>
 <table>
     <tr>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

As you can see, the overview page should show Title and Date. If you click on the Title (there must be an "a href=" somewhere like next to the "h5") you should redirect to a page where Title, Date and Description of the specific job offer is shown.

I know that if I set json[0].Description, it will display me the first data for Description. But how can I set the hyperlink and the Code, so that the detail page shows me data for job 1, if I click on job 1, data for job 2 if I click on job 2...? Otherwise I would have to create HTML files for like 200 jobs (json[0], json[1]…) and this can't be the way JSON is meant to.

I have no idea how to solve this...

Comment: Have you considered a *loop*?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! What would that look like? I have literally no idea of JSON or JavaScript... :-/

Comment: Then maybe you should learn those things if you're going to use them? I'd strongly recommend a structured JS tutorial.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a few JS tutorials before asking. StackOverflow isn't meant to do the job for you, but help guide you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More an advice than a real answer to the original question, here is a workaround.

Depending on how your website is built, you should choose a SPA-like (Single Page Application) behavior for your detailed view rather than another full web page.

This will prevent loading a full page for just few data's to display.
This way, clicking on a table row will trigger a `slideToggle()` ([jquery native function](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)) which will display additionnal content.
Something like this :

```js
const json = [{
    "Title": "Developer",
    "Date": "now",
    "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Secretary",
    "Date": "next month",
    "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Postman",
    "Date": "now",
    "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  }
];

var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  td = $('<td/>');
  td.append("<h5>" + json[i].Title + "</h5>");
  td.append("<p><strong>Date:</strong> " + json[i].Date + "&nbsp;</p>");
  td.append("<div style='display:none'><strong>Description:</strong>" + json[i].Description + "</div>");
  $(tr).append(td);
  $('#table').append(tr);
}
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find("div").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#table {
  width: 100%;
}

#table tr {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

#table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

> By the way, be careful, your json isn't properly formatted : missing commas between each object, and title/position are mixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I worked around a bit and your code helped me a lot solving my issue and understanding JSON better!

Comment: Glad it helped ^_^